# Orator ORM: How to change database?

Tags: python, orm

On Orator [documentation](https://orator-orm.com/docs/0.9/basic_usage.html#accessing-connections), I can only find a way to change connection. I've already checked the Orator [Connection Model](https://github.com/sdispater/orator/blob/0.9/orator/connections/connection.py), but database setter is nowhere to be found.

Is there a way to change the database on Orator ORM without creating multiple connections? Thank you.

Github Issue Link: https://github.com/sdispater/orator/issues/326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in the github issue by josephmancuso:

> No. You'll need to switch between the connections.
>
> A connection is just a group of database settings.

You can technically do so if you query manually, but this bypasses the whole benefit of using an ORM:

```
db.select('select * from db2.table') #runs a raw query
```